# Math contest proof equation problem

Tags: contest-math

Could someone help me with this?

If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then show that $$\frac{m}{
\sqrt n}+ \frac{m}{\sqrt[4]{n}} \neq 1$$.

Comment: Is it $$\frac{m}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{m}{\sqrt[4]{n}} \neq 1\;?$$

Comment: That second term is supposed to be a fraction, right?

Comment: This is obviously true as written, since $m\sqrt[4]{n}\geq 1$ so the left hand side is $>1$. So agreed with @DanielFischer, did you transcribe the problem incorrectly?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that may be a mis-edit

Comment: No, it should be right

Comment: The second term was the square root of the square root of n, which should be equal to the fourth root of n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{m}{\sqrt n}+ \frac{m}{\sqrt[4]{n}} = 1 \implies \frac{m}{\sqrt n}\left(1+\sqrt[4]{n}\right) = 1 $$

Or $m(1+\sqrt[4]{n}) = \sqrt{n}$.  Squaring, $m^2(1+\sqrt[4]{n})^2 = n$.

---

Suppose $n$ is not a perfect fourth power, so $r = \sqrt[4] n$ is irrational.  Then we have $(1+r)^2 = N$, for some factor of $n$.  So $r = \sqrt N -1$ and $N$ is not a perfect square.

However $r^4 = N^2+6N+1-4(1+N)\sqrt N= n$ makes $\sqrt N$ rational.  Hence this case leads to contradiction.

---

So we need $n$ to be a perfect fourth power, say $n = k^4$.  So $m^2(1+k)^2 = k^4$.

So $m(1+k) = k^2 \implies$ for all primes $p|(1+k)$, we must have $p | k$.  This is not possible, hence we cannot have a solution.

Comment: Would one not also need to show that $1+\sqrt[4]{n}\neq \sqrt{N}$ for integers $n,N?$

Comment: @L.F. Covered explaining the other case.

Comment: Surprisingly simple